# How to solve the error target script cannot be loaded as python module when django app deploy without port number

Tags: python, django, apache, ubuntu

When i deploy django app on aws ec2 instance using ubuntu 16.04 server then it gives an error:

```
[Sun May 05 16:13:25.466264 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 5649:tid 140262036731648] [remote 157.50.50.61:56646] mod_wsgi (pid=5649): Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/simple_django_project/django_project/django_project/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sun May 05 16:13:25.466312 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 5649:tid 140262036731648] [remote 157.50.50.61:56646] mod_wsgi (pid=5649): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/simple_django_project/django_project/django_project/wsgi.py'.
[Sun May 05 16:13:25.466388 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 5649:tid 140262036731648] [remote 157.50.50.61:56646] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sun May 05 16:13:25.466409 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 5649:tid 140262036731648] [remote 157.50.50.61:56646]   File "/var/www/html/simple_django_project/django_project/django_project/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Sun May 05 16:13:25.466413 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 5649:tid 140262036731648] [remote 157.50.50.61:56646]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Sun May 05 16:13:25.466429 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 5649:tid 140262036731648] [remote 157.50.50.61:56646] ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName pythontestdjangoapp.tk
   ServerAlias www.pythontestdjangoapp.tk

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/simple_django_project

    ErrorLog/var/www/html/simple_django_project/django_project/logs/error.log
    CustomLog 
     /var/www/html/simple_django_project/django_project/logs/debug.log 
    combined


   <Directory />
     #Options FollowSymLinks
     Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
     AllowOverride All
     Require all granted
   </Directory>

   <Directory 
     /var/www/html/simple_django_project/django_project/django_project/>
        <Files wsgi.py>
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Files>
   </Directory>
   WSGIDaemonProcess django_project python- 
   path=/var/www/html/simple_djnago_project/django_project python- 
   home=/var/www/html/simple_django_project/myvenv
   WSGIProcessGroup django_project


   WSGIScriptAlias / 
   /var/www/html/simple_django_project/django_project/django_project/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

When i start apache server then it gives me an internal server error

Comment: are you using your virtual environment for your project?

Comment: yes..m using virtual environment...

Comment: did you forget to activate it? because it cannot find the `django` package that you installed in your virtual environment..

Comment: no..i activate this virtual environment

Comment: thare are two folders make under my virtual environment...django, Djanago 2.2.1

Comment: I mean in your script you should

Comment: which script are you talking about?